# Unable to access JSON fields in a AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm new to Php/Jquery Programming, and i past all this day trying figuring how to access to a JSON field from a Jquery AJAX call:

I'm using codeingniter, and in my controller the related code is:

```
if( $this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
{
    $view_data['test'] = 'ajax';
    echo json_encode( $view_data ); 
}
else
{
    $view_data['test'] = 'not ajax';                              
    $data = array(
            'javascripts' => array(
            'js/jquery.dataTables.js',
            'js/zona/dataTable_zone.js',
            'js/zona/gestisci_zone.js',
            'js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js' ,
            'js/jquery.ui.error-panel.js',  
            'js/jquery.validate.min.js' ,
            'js/localization/messages_it.js'
        ),
        'style_sheets' => array(
            'css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css' => 'screen',                 
            'css/jquery.dataTables.css' => 'screen'
        ),
        'content' => $this->load->view( 'zona/gestisci_zone', $view_data, TRUE )
    );

    $this->load->view( $this->template, $data);
}
```

`
In the view the related code is

```
<div id="id_test">  <p><?php echo $test ?> </p></div>
```

and in the javascript file the related AJAX code is

`$.ajax( {                                 type:"POST",
                                        url:this_url, 
                                         dataType: 'json',
    data:   post_data,
                                            success:    function(data){

```
                                             console.log(data);
                                             console.log($("id_test").empty());
                                        $("#id_test").empty().append(data.test);
                                        },
                                        error: function(data){

                                        alert("error");
```

);`

in this way the AJAX output is `Array{"test":"ajax"}`

my expected behavior is that using  `$("#id_test").empty().append(data.test);` the AJAX output will be just the word ajax, but it just return a blank div.
I've tried to access in many modes but i didnt figured how to accomplish this.
Maybe i'm missing something because of my lack of experience or i'm using a wrong approach.
Any advice please? :)

After a little of debug i've arrived to conclusion that is a plaintext / false JSON problem.
it is returning just the text rapresentation of the array and not a json array. Now, how i can send the correct json array from controller? (i already forced mimetype to application/json with no effects)

Comment: What does a console.log(data) give you, as well as console.log($("id_test").empty()) ?

Comment: in success method try to debug data like console.log(data), let me know if it shows any result

Comment: i'm at home now. As soon as i can i will give a try the both!Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps there's just a typo in your code? The line that says view_data['test'] = 'ajax'; is lacking a $ sign for $view_data

Comment: Almost sure that is a cut/paste typo..but i'll double check tomorrow morning :)

Comment: The $view_data['test'] = 'ajax'; issue was only a cut/paste typo.

Comment: console.log(data) gives Array{"test":"ajax"}  and  console.log($("id_test").empty());gives []

Comment: `$("#id_test").empty().append(data.test);` ?

Comment: "my expected behavior is that using $("#id_test").empty().append(data.test); the AJAX output will be just the word ajax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `dataType` and not `datatype`. I believe that's the problem, seems like it's not parsing the returned data as json and as a string instead.

Comment: I agree - syntax and proper case is very important with javascript.

Comment: i'm aware of dataType,and I tried this too, but with dataType i've neither the Array{"test":"ajax"} output. Maybe is there another hidden problem.. ?

Comment: with datatype it will return Array{"test":"ajax"}, with dataType it will return nothing but adding a error function will show the alert(msg) in the error function. It seems a bit strange behaviour for me :)

Comment: I found the error(s). I was ECHOing some values in the model for debug pourposes and the result of the echo was the Array part of Array{"test":"ajax"} plus few spares whitespaces left before initial  <?php tag...resulting in a response made by "{whitespaces}+Array+JSON_encoded array"!! 2 days burned. BTW now it's working like a charm with dataType:'json' ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to toggle between json and jsonp if still you do not succeed. jQuery has 2 options "json" and "jsonp"

Comment: `jsonp` is for cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an error handler in the ajax call so you can tell whether it is executed successfully or not. And I think you have to use **data.d**

Comment: `data.d` ? why would you think that ?

Comment: Sorry, come from an asp.net background. Please ignore data.d

Comment: what do you you mean for error handler? an error:function()? sorry i'm new to web programming:)

Comment: yeb, just like the success you have error: function(msg){aler(msg);} to show the error message if ajax have one.

Comment: i've got a error message but in addition to switching feom (incorrect) datatype: 'json',to (correct) dataType : 'json' :(

Comment: Now since you are sure it working, can you try to alert(data); just to see if you have data return back from ajax. Then you will know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess but... syntax error maybe?

```
if( $this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
{
    view_data['test'] = 'ajax';
    // dont you mean $view_data?

    echo json_encode( $view_data ); 
}
```

Comment: Almost sure that is a cut/paste typo..but i'll double check tomorrow morning :)

Comment: you also need to iterate over the data object using a for loop

Comment: it was a cut/paste Typo! Do you intend iterate the javascript data array ? in which mode?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, in order for your `<div id="id_test">  <p><?php echo $test ?> </p></div>` to be replaced by the word "ajax" from `$.ajax()`, try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:this_url, 
  dataType: 'json',
  data: post_data, 
  success: function(data){
    $("#id_test").empty().append(data.test);
  }
});
```

Since you mention that the `data` returns `Array{"test":"ajax"}`, you can access the returned JavaScript object in this manner `data.test`

Comment: Try this, `$('#id_test').empty().html(data.test);`

Comment: "my expected behavior is that using $("#id_test").empty().append(data.test); the AJAX output will be just the word ajax"